# how to write output variables into a dictionary or list using expect

Tags: shell, expect

I have an expect script which has some output values that are extracted from a server and printed on the screen. How can I write these values into a list or a key value pair mapped into a file using expect ? If not possible using expect, how can I do so and how can I invoke my script into the other script?

part of my script after logging into my server

```
send "menu\r"
expect "*:*"
regexp {.*(Name.*)(Path.*)(State.*)} $expect_out(buffer) matched op1 op2 op3
#puts \n
send_user "Name is: "
puts [string trim $op1]
send_user "Path is: "
puts [string trim $op2]
send_user "State is: "
puts [string trim $op3]
```

So for the output variables `$op1`, `$op2`, `$op3` how can I store their values into a list or dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

You can use any TCL data structure: [list](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/list.htm) or [array](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/array.htm) (they actually hashas, since index can be string) or [dict](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/dict.htm).